# How to setup data-binding with records from a database?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm using the SQLite for my xamarin forms application. I was wondering how i could bind a list  to a record  of numbers stored on the database? Should I simply bind to the class used to generate the database table or should i generate a list from the records retrieved from the database and set my binding  to that?

Comment: You can do either.  Typically in MVVM apps you would create a ViewModel to bind to instead of using your data model directly, but either approach will work.  Data binding is well documented and there are many sample apps available for you to study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a list from a retrieved records and then bind that particular list in which records are there.